# Google Maps not working on iOS and TestFlight

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-maps

I will be eternally in debt and grateful to anyone who can share with me or point me to the right direction on how to make react-native-maps from Airbnb work on iOS TestFlight.

Right now following the steps from the react-native-maps guide is impossible, I had to use the example in the repo to have it working on the Simulator but when I push to TestFlight the app crash instantly.

Again, I will be in eternal debt to anyone who can help me solve this!